# Python: Using property get/set to run on sub-class function

Tags: python

I have a setup that looks something like this simplified setup:

```
class WorkerBee():
   def __init__(self):
      self.x = 1
      self.old_x = None
   def update_x(self, val):
      self.update_old_x()
      self.x = val

   def _update_old_x(self):
      self.old_x = self.x

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):
      self.bee = WorkerBee()

    def updated_WorkerBee(self):
      print('yay, it was updated')
```

I understand the use of `@property` to do a get - set setup for an attribute. But in this case, I'm trying to figure out how I can directly call the `WorkerBee` methods (there are more than 1 in my case....) that would also trigger `MainClass.updated_WorkerBee()`

```
In:
main = MainClass()
main.bee.update_x(2)  

Out:
yay, it was updated
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: as an aside, "subclass" is not standard terminology here. That implies an inheritance relationship, which there is none here.

Comment: Doh - I just wanted to sound cool.   Updated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a reference to the main object to the bee, like a parent:

```
class WorkerBee:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        self.x = 1
        (...)
```

and then use it in your update methods within WorkerBee, to update main too:

```
 def update_x(self, val):
     self.update_old_x()
     self.x = val
     self.main.updated_WorkerBee()
```

To do that, pass the main to the bee when you create it:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bee = WorkerBee(self)
```

Comment: hmm, got it.  That makes sense.   Are you able to generalize it so that passing main is optional....? (I want WorkerBee to be a standalone class too, and not depend on MainClass)

Comment: yes, you can say `main = None` in the WorkerBee init def to make it an optional parameter. then have an `if self.main is not None` check where you call it.

i might avoid that though, and perhaps give a no-op main instead, to avoid such branching.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out if I can use a decorator within WorkerBee, that does nothing unless MainClass changes its defintion

Comment: Decorator sounds like overkill. With a no-op main I mean you could have a MainClass `updated_WorkerBee` that just does nothing, when you want to disable it.

Comment: sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean with the 'does nothing unless..'. Also I'm not sure why you want the Bee to work with and without a main. Maybe you can make a new question about that, I think this one is clear about the basics it covers now.